# Favicon not working in Next.js dynamic routed page

Tags: next.js

I have the following `_documents.js` file

```
import NextDocument, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ColorModeScript } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export default class Document extends NextDocument {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="images/logos/tab_icon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <ColorModeScript />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

Favicon is `renamed` to `tab_icon.ico`

All my static pages are correctly showing the icon in the tabs. However for the dynamiclly routed pages it is not showing. I am using `getStaticProps` with `getStaticPaths`.

Here is the dynamic page structure

```
 - index.js
 - /folder
 - /folder/[id].js
```

My NextJS version is `Next.js v12.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your link path to your icon. It seems you did not write the `/` as the first character. As you know in Next.js to get access to files that are located in the `public` folder you should start your path with the `/` slash.

```
<link rel="icon" href='/images/logo/tab_icon.ico' />
```

Comment: ah that did the trick, i feel dumb now. Wonder why it was working with normal static pages though?

Comment: Static pages are often cached more aggressively by both browsers and Content Delivery Networks (CDNs) because they don't change frequently. On the other hand, dynamically generated pages are typically not cached as aggressively, and resources like favicons might not be retained between page navigations.